# Shrink table when decreasing window size to prevent scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have an HTML that has a navigation bar on top, a div with some wells and then another div which is the "main page" div.
So the main page div has a table in it with several columns. This table is a form and almost all are inputs. I have tried to add one more column there and the page gives me an overflow to the right.

I want to prevent it and make the table to be able to shrink based on the screen. I have this problem on a 15'' screen. Though on a 32'' screen there is no problem and everything is ok.

My CSS code for the table and the HTML is and from what I see the inputs on the table should be able to shrink base on the default values that they get:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#mileCtlTable{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:auto;
    border: 3px solid black;
    //white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}


#mileCtlTable thead td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-style:oblique;
    text-align:center;
    //white-space: nowrap;
    margin:0vw;
    background-color: navy;
    color:white;
}

#mileCtlTable tbody td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    //width:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}



#mileCtlTable td,#mileCtlTable th{
    padding: 0.2vw 0.5vw;
}

#mileCtlTable input{
    text-align: center;
    //white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0.2vw 0.5vw;
}
```

Comment: So you want the table to shrink if it does not fit in the screen?

Comment: yes exactly this and i do not want the table to have internal overflow.

Comment: So you want the input cell sizes to grow as well?

Comment: suppose that it takes the size of the column data yes. Lets say that if it is empty to go to column width , else to expand. and i would like to be able to wrap also column headers. But i think that it is something easy in css that i do not know that could make this expand or shrink automatically

Comment: I have added  input{width: 100%;} and it seems to be correct now.

Comment: If you want, you can also set `max-width` so that the table never gets wider than a certain amount, but will get skinnier according to the page width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added

```
input{width: 100%;}
```